# Get weird result when calculating distance between two points, using latitude longitude?

Tags: distance, java, latitude-longitude

I use algorithm (see: [calculating distance between two points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16794680/5723609)) to calculate distance between two points. but it get wrong result, see Java code:

```
/**
 * group1：set latitude to 89
 */
// set longitude1 = 0, longitude2 = 1
System.out.println(distance(89, 89, 0, 1, 0 , 0)); // 1941.0            result1

// set longitude1 = 0, longitude2 = 2
System.out.println(distance(89, 89, 0, 2, 0 , 0)); // 3881.0            result2

// set longitude1 = 0, longitude2 = 179
System.out.println(distance(89, 89, 0, 179, 0 , 0)); // 222381.0        result3

// set longitude1 = 0, longitude2 = 180
System.out.println(distance(89, 89, 0, 180, 0 , 0)); // 222390.0        result4

/**
 * group2：set latitude to 0
 */
// set longitude1 = 0, longitude2 = 1
System.out.println(distance(0, 0, 0, 1, 0 , 0)); // 111195.0            result5

// set longitude1 = 0, longitude2 = 2
System.out.println(distance(0, 0, 0, 2, 0 , 0)); // 222390.0            result6

// set longitude1 = 0, longitude2 = 179
System.out.println(distance(0, 0, 0, 179, 0 , 0)); // 19903892          result7

// set longitude1 = 0, longitude2 = 180
System.out.println(distance(0, 0, 0, 180, 0 , 0)); // 20015087          result8
```

In group1:

```
a = result2 - result1 = 1940 

b = result4 - result3 = 9
```

In group2:

```
c = result6 - result5 = 111195

d = result8 - result7 = 111195
```

It's very strange. `c = d`, group2 is right, but `a ≠ b`, group1 is wrong.

How do I solve this issue?

**Is there other higher accuracy algorithm for calculate distance between two coordinate points?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No issue here - the formula calculates shortest path across the globe which in case #3 and #4 goes across the pole, **not** along a line of constant latitude which you are assuming.

Cross reference results using this [tool here](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).